# How to handle blank form value in python

Tags: python

I have 2 form fields in my html code, which hits to python script. Everything works perfectly if i provide both input in form. But in my case, 2nd field is optional. I am getting blank result when i submit form with 1st field only. How to handle my code to run even when 2nd field is blank/null

python code:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
first=form["firstSix"].value
last=form["lastFour"].value
```

Comment: We'd need more context than that to help you. What kind of data is being submitted into the form? What are you doing with the data you are retrieving? Please try to be more specific.

Comment: `cgi.FieldStorage()` will return you dict right?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940235/working-in-python-cgi-with-form-empty-input-error

Answer (score 0):

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
first=form["firstSix"].value

if form["lastFour"]:
    last=form["lastFour"].value
else:
    form["lastFour"] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if something is empty with a boolean.

```
if not form["lastFour"]:
    print "lastFour is empty!"
else:
    print "lastFour has a value!"
```

Any string that is empty is considered false, and and that has a value is true. So `""` is false and `"Hello World!"` is true. If the form value equals `None`, you might have to check for that too.

```
if not form["lastFour"]:
    print "lastFour is empty!"
elif form["lastFour"] == None:
    print "lastFour has is empty!"
else:
    print "lastFour has a value!"
```

Comment: If i pass value, "lastFour has a value" is printed, but if i pass blank, "lastFour is empty" is not printed. Anyways, i got the solution by counting length of my dictionary form and manipulating my code after that.

Comment: Awesome! It should work though, I tested it in my console, and it worked. If `form["lastFour"]` is the value `None` you might have to check for that too.